Why creating application is failing?
I want to create an app following the url from a github project but heroku throws error:
https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/ibandominguez/wordpress-heroku
I expected to see the app up and running in a few minutes but when I added the application name and clicked Deploy, the application was not created and I got this error instead:
App creation failed. Please ensure you have valid values in the above form fields.
Also it threw this:
Couldn't find either the add-on service or the add-on plan of "cloudcube:free".
Is it because I have a free account?

Did you look at the list of available plans? Free is indeed not there.

That repo hasn’t been updated in at least 3 years. In that time, Heroku removed free plans of various data storage add-ons. Cloudcube is obviously one of the add-ons affected given the error message.

You’re also going to have an issue with the jawsdb add-on, as its free plan seems to have since been renamed as kitefin.
